# MobX - Select single item in array, unselect all others?

Tags: mobx

I have the following observable array of search engines.

```
@observable favoriteSearchEngine = [
    { 'provider' : 'google', 'selected': true },
    { 'provider' : 'yahoo', 'selected': false },
    { 'provider' : 'bing', 'selected': false },
];
```

The user should only be able to **select one at a time** from the UI. So if they choose `yahoo` for example, yahoo would get `selected: true` and any other provider would get `selected: false`

This action handles the click:

```
@action onClickFavoriteSearchEngine = (provider) => {
    alert(provider); // yahoo shows here
    // How to do this step, only selected provider true and falsify all others in the array?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution given by @mweststrate works great, but since you are using an [action](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/action.html) (which also is a [transaction](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/transaction.html)), you could just unselect the previously selected, and select the new one if you would prefer:

```
@action onClickFavoriteSearchEngine = (provider) => {
  alert(provider); // yahoo shows here

  favoriteSearchEngine.forEach(e => e.selected = false);
  favoriteSearchEngine.find(e => e.provider === provider).selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would introduce a single observable representing selection, and derive the selected state from that:

```
@observable selection = null
@observable  favoriteSearchEngine = [
    { 'provider' : 'google', 'selected': function() {
        return selection === this
    }
]
```

If you now assign another engine to the selection a few times, you will see that the `selected` state of the engines will update accordingly

(N.B. don't use arrow functions if declaring a plain object + derivation like this, to avoid issues with `this`)

Comment: Didn't work for some reason, I'd still be interested in knowing how it would work. `@observable selection = null` do you do an action and assign `this.selection = provider`? I tried but didn't work. I don't think I fully understand how this works :(

Comment: Indeed, could you maybe create a fiddle to demonstrate your problem? You could for example fork: http://jsbin.com/qusoye/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: specifically, assign something like: `favoriteSearchEngine[0]` (or change the computed property to match on name basis instead of on reference)

Comment: I tried to change up the fiddle but got errors. No worries, since the above solution works! Thank you mweststrate :)